# Error 330 for a basic Safecracker form

Tags: safecracker

I've setup a template at test/index that simply contains the following;

```
{exp:safecracker channel="quote_request"}
   <input name="title" type="text">
   <input name="my_custom_field" type="text">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:safecracker}
```

However, the page is simply returning a "This webpage is not available" and "Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error."

I do have a channel called quote_request. I'm using ExpressionEngine 2.5.5 and Safecracker 2.1.

Wondered if anyone else has had this issue before? :/

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, seems that the GZip compression causes this issue. All sorted.